# Wordpress Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /wp-includes/theme.php on line 2241

Tags: php, wordpress

```
if ( is_array( $args[0] ) && isset( $_wp_theme_features['post-thumbnails'] ) ) {
            $args[0] = array_unique( array_merge( $_wp_theme_features['post-thumbnails'][0], $args[0] ) );
        }
```

[image]
Im getting this error after upgrading php from 7.4 to php 8.0 please help how to fix this?

Comment: This is a warning only. Please share what is broken as otherwise there is nothing to fix. And your code has line 1-3, you may want to show line 2241.

Comment: One of the things your expects to be an array is in fact a boolean. We don't know which one  or why. You provided no debugging info and no [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]. Without more details we cannot help you except by rephrasing the error message as I have just done.

Comment: @hakre, i am showing the only line of code where got warning. I am not able to run the site due to above warning. attached screen shot for your reference.

Comment: Sorry if it appeared nit-picking, but please see in the question there _are_ three lines, and if you read also the comment by ADyson, there is already a problem to locate the cause of error with a single line, and having three lines instead of one does not help. However it could help, if you have the same format in the file (three lines instead of one), so that the error message can point more precisely to the actual expressions that is reading a boolean as if it would be an array. Don't go to fight with code you can't win. Play with it instead.